# Weird Orbit feature with 2.80

Tags: modifiers, multiresolution, navigation

When you use the multiresolution modifier in blender, whenever you orbit the subdivisions have the same effect as if turning off and when you stop orbiting they are displayed again.  I believe this is a feature of blender to make orbiting faster, but I want to turn it off.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Options* dropdown of the sculpt mode, deactivate *Fast Navigate*.

[image: Options screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it :D